How do I merge two LEFT JOIN rows that cannot coexist into one?
So I have a result like this gotten from multiple LEFT JOIN statement where one join is available, the other is null
user_id | country | purpose_id
2         CA       NULL
2         NULL     367
2         NG       NULL
2         NULL     368

I want to be able to convert this to
user_id | country | purpose_id
2         CA       367
2         NG       368

But I cannot seem to get it with my JOIN statement
SELECT
    cs.user_id,
    UPPER(country_term.slug),
    purpose_term.term_id
FROM
    wp_user_services cs
INNER JOIN wp_posts v ON
    v.ID = cs.visa_id AND v.post_status = 'publish'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON
    tr.object_id = v.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON
    tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy IN('country', 'purpose')
LEFT JOIN wp_terms country_term ON
    tt.term_id = country_term.term_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'country'
LEFT JOIN wp_terms purpose_term ON
    purpose_term.term_id = tt.term_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'purpose'
WHERE
    cs.user_id = 2;

Anyone with ideas?
EDIT:
Fiddle

What is the relationship between country and purpose_id? How do we know 367 goes with CA and not NG?  You might need to include country_term.term_id in your output to clarify the relationships.

Please also include tr.term_taxonomy_id

Usually when people ask questions like this they include source data (not just results). Please provide example records from wp_user_services, wp_posts, wp_term_relationships , and wp_term_taxonomy.

@BartMcEndree I have added a fiddle

It's ambiguous. I don't think you can do that without returning errors from mysql. I was going to suggest sub-queries... Are there any other tables?

This is all the involved table @admcfajn

How many rows? You might be better off processing in a script.

It is looking like an option now @admcfajn

Your question is still very hard to understand. Yes, you provided a fiddle, but this means your question doesn't stand alone. And the fiddle contains incredible many rows, much more than would be required to understand your issue. Please provide a few rows of sample input data directly in your question that correspond to the expected result.

I solved my problem with nested query after trying to write a PHP script, I realised I used nested loop. It works now.
SELECT DISTINCT
    cs.consultant_id,
    UPPER(country_term.slug) country,
    purpose.term_id
FROM
    wp_consultant_services cs
INNER JOIN wp_posts v ON
    v.ID = cs.visa_id AND v.post_status = 'publish'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON
    tr.object_id = v.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON
    tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'country'
INNER JOIN wp_terms country_term ON
    tt.term_id = country_term.term_id
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        purpose_term.term_id term_id,
        tr2.object_id object_id
    FROM
        wp_term_relationships tr2
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2 ON
        tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id AND tt2.taxonomy = 'purpose'
    INNER JOIN wp_terms purpose_term ON
        purpose_term.term_id = tt2.term_id
) purpose
ON
    purpose.object_id = tr.object_id
WHERE
    cs.consultant_id = 2 AND cs.visa_id IS NOT NULL AND cs.status = 1;

I would love ideas on how to improve this if there is room for improvement. :)

SELECT
    cs.user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tt.taxonomy = 'country' THEN UPPER(country_term.slug) END) AS country,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tt.taxonomy = 'purpose' THEN purpose_term.term_id END) AS purpose_id
FROM
    wp_user_services cs
INNER JOIN wp_posts v 
    ON v.ID = cs.visa_id AND v.post_status = 'publish'
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr 
    ON tr.object_id = v.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
    AND tt.taxonomy IN ('country', 'purpose')
LEFT JOIN wp_terms country_term 
    ON tt.term_id = country_term.term_id 
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'country'
LEFT JOIN wp_terms purpose_term 
    ON purpose_term.term_id = tt.term_id 
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'purpose'
WHERE
    cs.user_id = 2
GROUP BY
    cs.user_id,
    tt.term_taxonomy_id;


This is correct only if the natural keys are present in all joins such that only one row per user_id is returned. If mutliple rows per user_id are returned then this will pick the greatest slug in a binary order and the greatest term_id in whatever order that data type uses for sorting. There'll be no guarantee of a relationship between the returned slug and term_id.

Thank you, Robin. This still doesn't work if tried in the fiddle.

The relationships here seem to be that a consultant is issued a visa for a country and has purpose(s) for such a visit. Country and purpose(s) can therefore be aggregated eg
with cte as
(SELECT cs.consultant_id, 
       v.id vid,
       tt.term_taxonomy_id,tt.taxonomy,tt.term_id 
FROM wp_consultant_services cs 
INNER JOIN wp_posts v ON v.ID = cs.visa_id AND v.post_status = 'publish' 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = v.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy IN('country', 'purpose') 
),
cte1 as
(select consultant_id,vid,taxonomy,cte.term_id,country_term.slug
from cte 
left  JOIN wp_terms country_term ON country_term.term_id = cte.term_id
where cte.taxonomy ='country'
union all
select consultant_id,vid,taxonomy,cte.term_id,purpose_term.slug
from cte 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms purpose_term ON purpose_term.term_id = cte.term_id
where cte.taxonomy ='purpose'
)
select cte1.consultant_id,cte1.vid,
        max(cte1.slug) country,
        group_concat(cte2.slug) purpose
from cte1 
left join cte1 cte2 on cte2.consultant_id = cte1.consultant_id and cte2.vid = cte1.vid and cte2.taxonomy = 'purpose'
where cte1.taxonomy = 'country'
group by cte1.consultant_id,cte1.vid

note that whilst country is unique to visa a visa could be used many times for different purposes..

You need a query like this...your term_relationships table has a whole bunch of attributes that can belong to the object. From those you are interested only in the country and purpose relationships, and you want to get those "in the same row". Here I've used max(case()) to do that, since there are only two. You could use GROUP_CONCAT if you had a bunch to deal with. In my native Oracle I would use PIVOT.
SELECT cs.consultant_id, UPPER(country_term.slug), purpose_term.term_id 
FROM wp_consultant_services cs 
INNER JOIN wp_posts v ON v.ID = cs.visa_id AND v.post_status = 'publish' 
INNER JOIN   
  (select tr.object_id,max(case when taxonomy = 'country' then tt.term_taxonomy_id end) country_id,max(case when taxonomy = 'purpose' then tt.term_taxonomy_id end) purpose_id 
  from  wp_term_relationships tr
  join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
  WHERE tt.taxonomy IN('country', 'purpose') 
  group by tr.object_id
  ) tx ON tx.object_id = v.id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms country_term ON country_term.term_id = tx.country_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms purpose_term ON purpose_term.term_id = tx.purpose_id 
WHERE cs.consultant_id = 2 AND cs.visa_id IS NOT NULL AND cs.status = 1; 

